# Disable unselected options from optgroup in mulitiselect dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

In my multiselect i have several optgroups .
I want to allow user to select only one option from a optgroup . 
As soon user select any one option from any optgroup I want disable all other options from same group not for other optgroups .
I tried following code 
Html

```
    <option selected="selected" label="All" value="">All</option>
<optgroup label="fruits" class="fruit">
    <option label="apple" value="1">Apple</option>
    <option label="pear" value="2">Pear</option>
    <option label="orange" value="3">Orange</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="berries" class="berries">
    <option label="strawberry" value="4">Strawberry</option>
    <option label="raspberry" value="5">Raspberry</option>
    <option label="blueberry" value="6">Blueberry</option>
</optgroup>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#fruits").change(function () {
    $("#fruits option").filter(":selected").parent("optgroup").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Jsbin Link 
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OxIveXI/1/watch?html,js,output)

above code disables all options from particular optgroup , i want that selected option should not be disabled .

Comment: You should post your code in here, in addition to the jsbin

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: `.filter(":selected")` this is selecting all the selected items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/imoSElOH/1/watch)</kbd>

Instead of doing this:

```
.parent('optgroup')
```

Do this:

```
.siblings('option')
```